# Ubuntu 16.04 display manager fails to recognize monitor

Tags: gnome

16.04 display manager does not recognize my samsung 204b monitor, 14.04 did . How do I load the older display manager into 16.04
In 16.04 Clicking on settings and display message comes up could not get screnn information. In 14.04 all info is shown.